# how to esp8266 port not detecting on arduino in window 11

Tags: arduino-esp8266, windows-11, com-port

windows 11 is not suitable for programming IoT devices like arduino and esp modules.
as it do not have com port by default.

so I tried to install `CH340 driver`
and com-port in
`windows device manager >> action >> added legacy hardware search for COM PORT`

still both arduino and platformio are unable to detect port or device.

any solution ?